# mac terminal tab size is inconsistent

Tags: c, terminal

I am reading 'The C language'. In this exercise, I am supposed to write a program that replaces a tab with equivalent spaces. here is my code,

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TABWIDTH 8

int main() {
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\t') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= TABWIDTH; ++i) {
                putchar(' ');
                //printf("%d\n", i);
            }
        } else {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that size of the tab is kinda inconsistent in the mac terminal. In my program, I assume it always going to be 8 spaces but in the terminal is not always 8.
here is the output I get
tab comes first

```
        k // this is tabed
        k // this is 8 spaces
```

tab comes after a character

```
k        k // this tabed
k          k // this 8 spaces
```

Comment: Yup, a `tab` is the number of spaces needed to get to the next `tab stop`. So if the `tab stop` is every 8 characters, and you've already got 7 characters, you only need one space.

Comment: thks for the answer, I just figured it out as soon I posted the question. Is there a way to delete the question

Comment: There is a way, but it's not really necessary. Just click the check mark next to the answer by Thomas, and that marks the question as solved.

Comment: If you feel that you really must delete the question, there should be a link under the tags. The links I see are *"share"*, *"edit"*, *"close"*, *"flag"*. I can't see the *"delete"* link because I'm not the OP. Keep in mind that deleting your questions is frowned upon. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The tab goes to the next tab-stop, which would be on columns 1,9,17,25,etc.
In your example, you have a **`k`** preceding the tab, but that isn't counted (because the tab goes to column 9), while the **`k`** before a space is counted (because spacing ignores tab-stops).